# Running PowerShell Script from shortcut with spaces in path

Tags: powershell, cmd, shortcut

One of our users needs to invoke a PowerShell script from a shortcut, as using the command line is probably beyond their abilities. The path of the script contains spaces, and I have been unable to successfully get the script to run from the shortcut. The target of the shortcut is:

```
powershell.exe -file "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx xxxx\Finance - Documents\Secure\xxx (Finance Officer)\Rent\Data File Loader - XXXXX\InvokeDataLoader.ps1"
```

(I have replaced names of people and the company with x's)

Clicking on the shortcut just briefly opens a cmd window (I think) so I have have been trying to diagnose the problem by running the command in cmd.exe. However when I try to do that I get an error message that it cannot find the path "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx" i.e. it is splitting the path on the first space. Enclosing the path with single or double quotes does not change this, and if I try to escape the spaces with backticks I get a message that the path does not exist.

Comment: If this is under a `\User` directory., does your account have permission there? What do you get from `DIR "C:\Users\xxxx\xxx xxx....ps1"`? What di you get from `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\xxxx\xxx xxx....ps1'"`?

Comment: I have used many PowerShell scripts run using a shortcut, _(to run without executionpolicy restrictions)_, which look very similar, and which are not affected by spaces, or parentheses. `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "%UserProfile%\xxxx xxxx\Finance - Documents\Secure\xxx (Finance Officer)\Rent\Data File Loader - XXXXX\InvokeDataLoader.ps1"` is perfectly fine. Are you sure that their execution policy isn't the problem?

Comment: Assuming the script path is correct, your command should work as shown (combination of `-File` with a _double_-quoted path), even with paths containing spaces. You can add `-NoExit` before `-File` to keep the console window open, which helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: thistledown, is there any reason why, despite being active on this site, you've not posted a response to the comments above? or updated your question content with further information?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response, have been chased for other things so not able to give this much attention.

Comment: @lit, I have permission for the directory, as does the user-I ran DIR on the directory and got the details.

Comment: @Compo, your suggestion works, do you know why this is so when using quotes does not?

Comment: @mklement0 I still seem to get the problem with double quotes but thanks for the -NoExit tip

Comment: @thistledown, it has nothing whatsoever to do with quotes, all of the responses, including mine used them. The only differences are that I used the full path to the PowerShell executable, asked PowerShell not to load the profile, _(which may not be what you need, depending upon what your script does)_, and I used a non default execution policy. My advice to determine which was your issue, is to remove each of those differences, one at a time until your problem reappears.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to change the PowerShell script itself to do this. When making the shortcut, simply set the target to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx xxxx\Finance - Documents\Secure\xxx (Finance Officer)\Rent\Data File Loader - XXXXX\InvokeDataLoader.ps1"
```